# Error accessing music file using laravel and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am working on a music app using laravel and jquery. The variable song throws the location of the file. But when the file is accessed via the third line of the code, there is error saying that the

`GET http://nightingale.test/storage/songs/15964389755f27b9bf70656.mp3 404 (Not Found)` .

Using the fourth command will allow me to access and play the music. Obviously the fourth line would be inefficient if a user wants to play another song. So any solution to this? Or I am just plain wrong. I have used the php symlink to connect.

Musicplayer.blade.php

```
<div id="playlist">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <li id="songtitle">{{$user->filename}}</li>
                <li id="songlocation">{{$user->location}}</li>
            @endforeach
</div>

<script>
    var song = $("#songlocation").text();
    console.log(song);

    var audio = new Audio('storage/songs/'+song);
    var audio = new Audio("storage/songs/15964389755f27b9bf70656.mp3");
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see as a result from console.log(song)?

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Also the URL you've given in the example returns a 404, so you need to verify you're building the URL strings properly

Comment: Did you create `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: Could be some whitespace / etc. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(song))` and see what that shows

Comment: i think the problem will be solved if you create unique ids and adapt your JS code as @CBroe said